# problem with updating state with useState and prev state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, web-applications, react-hooks

My code is like this:

```js
const [registryFormState, setRegistryFormState] = useState({
    email: null,
    username: null,
    password: null,
    confirmPassword: null,
  });

  const changeFormHandler = (value, inputIdentify) => {
    switch (inputIdentify) {
      case 'email':
        return setRegistryFormState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          email: value,
        }));
      case 'username':
        return setRegistryFormState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          username: value,
        }));
      case 'password':
        return setRegistryFormState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          password: value,
        }));
      case 'confirmPassword':
        return setRegistryFormState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          confirmPassword: value,
        }));
      default:
        return;
    }
  };
```

but when i change just email and console.log() the registryFormState, all the properties value change with the same value

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening. For demo purpose, just use one object property like `{ email: null }`

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you certain that the value of inputIdentity is correct? The problem could also be where you are using the state (the console log). The console log needs to have access to the new state. Could you show me that?

Comment: For read and refactor purpose, you may consider using return {
          ...prevState,
          [inputIdentify]: value,
        }, 
instead of the switch case

Answer (score -1):

You can use `registryFormState` to destructure instead of `prevState` like so:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Lol() {
  const [registryFormState, setRegistryFormState] = React.useState({
    email: null,
    username: null,
    password: null,
    confirmPassword: null
  });

  const changeFormHandler = (value, inputIdentify) => {
    switch (inputIdentify) {
      case "email":
        setRegistryFormState({
          ...registryFormState,
          email: value
        });
        break;
      case "username":
        setRegistryFormState({
          ...registryFormState,
          username: value
        });
        break;
      case "password":
        setRegistryFormState({
          ...registryFormState,
          password: value
        });
        break;
      case "confirmPassword":
        setRegistryFormState({
          ...registryFormState,
          confirmPassword: value
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={e => changeFormHandler(e.target.value, "email")} />
      <input onChange={e => changeFormHandler(e.target.value, "username")} />
      <input onChange={e => changeFormHandler(e.target.value, "password")} />
      <input
        onChange={e => changeFormHandler(e.target.value, "confirmPassword")}
      />
      <button onClick={() => console.log(registryFormState)}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```